# Multi-dimension String Array for MCQ app

Tags: android, arrays, string

I am trying to make an Simple MCQ app with the use of multidimension string array.
here is my code for `MainActivity`:

***My question is how can I define array of answers. I done addition but it won't work.***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
    TextView tvquestion, tvtotallength_yy, tvpresentindex_xx;
    Button previous, answer, next, result;

    int q, a, wrong, count;


    String[][] array = {{"Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", "Question 5", "Question 6", "Question 7", "Question 8", "Question 9", "Question 10"},
            {
                    "1answerA", "1answerB", "1answerC", "1answerD",
                    "2answerA", "2answerB", "2answerC", "2answerD",
                    "3answerA", "3answerB", "3answerC", "3answerD",
                    "4answerA", "4answerB", "4answerC", "4answerD",
                    "5answerA", "5answerB", "5answerC", "5answerD",
                    "6answerA", "6answerB", "6answerC", "6answerD",
                    "7answerA", "7answerB", "7answerC", "7answerD",
                    "8answerA", "8answerB", "8answerC", "8answerD",
                    "9answerA", "9answerB", "9answerC", "9answerD",
                    "10answerA", "10answerB", "10answerC", "10answerD",

            }
    };

    String[] ans = {"1answerA", "2answerD", "3answerC", "4answerA", "5answerB", "6answerB", "7answerA", "8answerC", "9answerD", "10answerD"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //initialing text view
        tvquestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvquestion);
        tvtotallength_yy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvyy);
        tvpresentindex_xx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvxx);

        //initializing button
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        result = (Button) findViewById(R.id.result);

        //initializing radio button
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogrp);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionA);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionB);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionC);
        rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.optionD);

        count = 0;
        wrong = 0;

        q = 0;
        a = 0;
        tvquestion.setText(array[0][q]);
        rb1.setText(array[1][q]);
        rb2.setText(array[1][q+1]);
        rb3.setText(array[1][q+2]);
        rb4.setText(array[1][q+3]);
        tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(q + 1));


        //setting the button to perform specific action
        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                q--;
                if (q == -1) {
                    q = array.length - 1;
                    tvquestion.setText(array[0][q]);
                    rb1.setText(array[1][q]);
                    rb2.setText(array[1][q + 4]);
                    rb3.setText(array[1][q + 8]);
                    rb4.setText(array[1][q + 12]);


                    tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(q + 1));
                } else {
                    tvquestion.setText(array[0][q]);
                    rb1.setText(array[1][a]);
                    rb2.setText(array[1][q + 4]);
                    rb3.setText(array[1][q + 8]);
                    rb4.setText(array[1][q + 12]);
                    tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(q + 1));
                }

            }
        });
        answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                        switch (checkedId) {
                            case R.id.optionA:
                                if (ans[q] == array[1][q]) {

                                    count++;
                                } else {
                                    wrong++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case R.id.optionB:
                                if (ans[q] == array[1][q + 4]) {

                                } else {
                                    wrong++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case R.id.optionC:
                                if (ans[q] == array[1][q + 8]) {
                                } else {
                                    wrong++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case R.id.optionD:
                                if (ans[q] == array[1][q + 12]) {

                                } else {
                                    wrong++;
                                }
                                break;

                        }

                    }
                });


            }

        });
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                radioGroup.clearCheck();

                q++;
                if (q == array.length) {
                    q = 0;
                    tvquestion.setText(array[0][q]);
                    rb1.setText(array[0][q]);
                    rb2.setText(array[0][q + 4]);
                    rb3.setText(array[0][q + 8]);
                    rb4.setText(array[0][q + 12]);

                    tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(q + 1));
                } else {

                    tvquestion.setText(array[0][q]);
                    rb1.setText(array[1][q]);
                    rb2.setText(array[1][q + 4]);
                    rb3.setText(array[1][q + 8]);
                    rb4.setText(array[1][q + 12]);
                    tvpresentindex_xx.setText(String.valueOf(q + 1));
                }
            }
        });

        result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct=" + count + " Incorrect=" + wrong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });    
    } 

}
```

Comment: How it works if I want to store that radioButton (Which is clhecked ) to an Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the actual answer

```
String[] ans = {"1answerA", "2answerD", "3answerC", "4answerA", "5answerB", "6answerB", "7answerA", "8answerC", "9answerD", "10answerD"};
```

you can store the index of the answer like this. Suppose you have 10 question and 4 choices which you are storing in an array. So you can define an int array of answers like this

```
int[] answers_index = new int[]{1,2,2,3,1,1,3,3,1,4,4};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing the index of the answers as an integer array. For example, if your answers are a,d,c and b respectively for 4 questions, your answer array can be
[0,3,2,1]. Then number the radio buttons so that button 1 has is represented by 0 and so on. Finally, when the user enters an answer, you can compare the number representation of the button to the integer value in your answer array to check for correctness.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. That's right but when I first open app it shows the option of the 10th question. why this is happening.

Comment: Sorry, I did not follow.. What do you mean by shows the option of the 10th question? Could you elaborate a bit?  P.S could you edit you code in the question to reflect current implementation?

Comment: when I open the app it shows the question 1 but options like 10answerA, 10answerB, 10answerC, 10answerD

Comment: and, by clicking on next button app stop runnig.

Comment: Hi, i just noticed that you are using the `array.length` function which is not very helpful as array is a 2D array. You basically need the number of questions so maybe you should call length on `array[0]` instead.. As for the issue with answers displayed, rather than setting indices as `q,q+4 `and so on, you can use `4*q,1+4*q,2+4*q,3+4*q`  . This should hopefully remove errors to some extent